# Error: "Can't resolve all parameters for e: (?)."

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have such kind of error after deployment to github-pages with **angular-cli**:

> Error:  "Can't resolve all parameters for e: (?)."

Local application works.
What steps would you recommend to do to find the problem place?

Tried with angular-cli **beta29** and **beta30**.

**UPD:** I've removed Router from the application for testing purposes. Not I have only one guess that it's something with DI.

**UPD2(FOUND THE PLACE)**:

The problem is with overwriting `RequestOptions`, so do:

```
export class RequestOptionsService extends RequestOptions {}
```

and for provider definition:

```
{ provide: RequestOptions, useClass: RequestOptionsService },
```

> It's still a question for me.

- do not overwrite `RequestOptions` constructor - error.
- overwrite `RequestOptions` constructor with empty parameter - no error
- overwrite `RequestOptions` constructor with parameters - error

This is the way how I overwrite the constructor:

```
constructor(options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
  super(options);
}
```

What could be wrong here?

**UPD3(Solved own case)**:

The problem indeed was with `RequestOptions`, so you should not do:

```
export class RequestOptionsService extends RequestOptions {}
```

but only:

```
export class RequestOptionsService extends BaseRequestOptions {}
```

Comment: Are you using `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, useHash: true)]`?

Comment: did not use, but just tried (RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) ) - same error - https://studytube.github.io/academy2-js

Comment: If it is Ok can you share your code? it will be more helpful!

Comment: unfortunately it's not just 3 lines. I have 25 services, each one is potential place of an issue.

Comment: Reading your comment in an answer below "The problem that it's minified version. And when I do prod build locally (ng serve --prod) -- it works! " i think it could be due to some library being already minified and so it gets broken when minified again (it happened to me in the past)

Comment: In the overwrite example, where is RequestOptionArgs defined? Is this supposed to be RequestOptions?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure:

- you have `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` in your `tsconfig.js`
- every service is not missing `@Injectable()` decorator
- components constructor injects your services (have them passed as
  parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Official example is:

```
 class MyOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
   search: string = 'coreTeam=true';
 }

 bootstrap(App, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: MyOptions}]);
```

In fact, `export class RequestOptionsService extends RequestOptions {}` should also work perfectly fine. May be it is angular-cli specific problem (i can do this on my setup).

If your service has non-optional parameter then `@Injectable()` is a must. Also parameters must be provided (`RequestOptionsArgs` in your case) or marked as `@Optional()`.