# Webpack application error

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I am a webpack newcomer, I have set it up but when i run my angular application from webpack I receive the following error. totally baffled as too why? I am not sure what else to do from this point onwards, any help is appreciated!

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Webpack console]

[image]

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
// OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
        app: './src/main.ts',
        vendor: './src/vendor.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'bundle.[name].js'
    },
    // watch: true,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'App'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader','angular2-template-loader?keepUrl=true'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            { 
      test: /\.(html|css)$/, 
      loader: 'raw-loader',
      exclude: /\.async\.(html|css)$/
    },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loaders: 'html-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**update:**
After adding the module.id to all the components I have created, I now receive this error.

[image: updated error]

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed a massive stack trace. When I see those I always try to figure out where it originates from, which file and where do I load it. On the right top corner, I see that it's coming from `bundle.polyfills.js`

Try temporarily disabling the polyfills entry point to see if that solves the issue. This will exclude that part of the code from being bundled.

```
polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
```

Here's what the Webpack docs say about the entry point.

> An entry point indicates which module webpack should use to begin
>   building out its internal dependency graph, webpack will figure out
>   which other modules and libraries that entry point depends on
>   (directly and indirectly).

You can read more on how to configure them [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points).

**UPDATE:**
To get a more meaningful message, add `devtool: "source-map"` into your Webpack config and see if that improves the output of the error message. Also, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022843/error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-e) post on SO? It might be applicable to your project too.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did look at the stacktrace, I managed to reduce the errors down to 1. I have updated the question with the current status of where I am. I had to add the module.id to the component

Comment: HI Haris, can you share you tsconfig.js? Something might be out of place there. Also, would it be possible to place the project (or a simplified version/hello world one) into a GitHub repo so I can try to recreate it locally?